# HTML Accessibility with grid data

Tags: html, css, accessibility, section508

Here is a js fiddle of my example output: http://jsfiddle.net/Hdzv8/ and below is the html. This is a pretty simple display of information but how would you make this accessible? I can make divs instead of tables but I cannot change the overall structure. The problem I have is there currently is no indication that "Weight" is a header for "16oz". How would you go about (from an accessability standpoint) labeling these sections as headers?

```
<table border="5">
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">Device Information</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Weight</b></td><td>16oz</td>
    <td><b>Height</b></td><td>3in</td>
    <td><b>Color</b></td><td>Brown</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Manufacturer</b></td><td>ACME Manufacturing</td>
    <td><b>Disposal Method</b></td><td>Shoot into the sun</td>
    <td><b>Alternate Color</b></td><td>Black</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Installation Manual</b></td><td>ACME 45.51.2009</td>
    <td><b>CCRC Code</b></td><td>CCRC551</td>
    <td><b>USNumber</b></td><td>55un</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The first row should be a [caption element](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H39.html) and CSS should be used instead of the border attribute and the b elements (should be th elements and in CSS `font-weight: bold;` - already by default on all known browsers but you can still write it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to have more than one record, I would leave this as a table (it's actually tabular data) but use `th` for the headers. If it's just the one record, I would go with `div`s or the like; seems more like presentation than just data then. HTMLDog has a few [tutorials on tables](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlintermediate/tables/) with a lot of advice on usage and accessibility.

**Edit**:
On second thought, I might just make a two-column, nine-row table where each row designates a field (e.g. weight, height) and the first column uses `th` to specify the row header and the second column uses a `td` for the actual value. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prSNj/) for a working example.

**Edit 2**:
[This related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084718/html-best-tag-for-labels-outside-of-forms) makes me think a definition or description list (using the `dl` tag) might be appropriate if you didn't want to use a `table`.

Comment: Ok easy enough, if I went with divs how would I specify that one div was a label (Height) and another was a value (160z)?

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, I think a `table` makes sense here. Writing up an edit now.

Comment: Hey that's great thanks! The only problem is I cannot change the UI, it has to go across so it would still be like this ( http://jsfiddle.net/AtKvC/2/ ). Do you know if blending td/th like that is acceptable?

Comment: Syntax-wise, totally acceptable. Judging by the [`scope` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_th_scope.asp), though, I'd say the W3C only meant for one `th` per row or column. So if you're really worried about semantics, maybe just stick with `td`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible with your real data (since I don't really see a clear column relation on your example)  but you could also consider transforming the whole markup in one (or more) description list e.g.

```
<tr>
   <td><b>Weight</b></td><td>16oz</td>
   ...
</tr>
```

could become

```
<dl>
    <dt>Weight</dt><dd>16oz</dd>
    ...
</dl>
```

otherwise you can still use table with `headers` attribute like so

```
<tr>
   <td id="header1"><b>Weight</b></td><td headers="header1">16oz</td>
   ...
</tr>
```

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H43

Comment: In your second example, you're associating data cell with another data cell. I believe it's forbidden : Technique H43 is meant to associate data cells with **header cells** (and also "sub"-header cells with other header cells). Data cell=`td` and header cell=`th`, it should be `<th id="header1">blah</th><td headers="header1">blah2</td>`

Comment: looking at http://www.jimthatcher.com/webcourse9.htm#wc9.3 it seems that any cell could be used as a target for headers attribute (not only th elements): 
> "you attach an id attribute to any cell you want to be a header cell. Then, add the id's of each header cell to the headers attribute of a data cell."

Answer (score 1):

If you have to keep that format, you don't need a table. Tables should only be used for rendering data that belongs naturally in a grid. If you have to keep this format you would be better off to use a description list instead and use CSS to style it into a bordered styled table.

If you do use a table, here is the proper way.
Use css instead of html attributes for styling 
Use 'strong' in place of 'b'
Use tabl
Tables must use proper html formatting

```
<table class="myborderclass">
<caption>
Device Information
</caption>
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th scope="col">Weight</th>
   <th scope="col">Height</b></th>
   <td scope="col">Color</b></th>
   <th scope="col">Manufacturer</b></th>
   <th scope="col">Disposal Method</b></th>
   <th scope="col">Alternate Color</b></th>
   <th scope="col">Installation Manual</b></th>
   <th scope="col">CCRC Code</b></th>
   <th scope="col">USNumber</b></th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>16oz</td>
   <td>3 inches</td>
   <td>Brown</td>
   <td>ACME</td>
   <td>Shoot into the sun</td>
   <td>Black</td>
   <td>ACME 45.51.2009</td>
   <td>CCRC551</td>
   <td>55un</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```